# Delete SMS on 4.4 even with my app set to default sms app

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, sendmessage

Like the title set, i did everything to set my app to be the default sms app, and it's works : i can send sms. 
Now i want to delete sms but it's not working.

This is the code to set to default (i've updated the manifest and all of it but i won't paste it ) :

```
int sdkvers = Integer.valueOf(Build.VERSION.SDK);
if (sdkvers >= 19) {
    final String packageName = context.getPackageName();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);

    intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Now the code to delete sms :

```
public void deleteSMS(Context context, String message) {
    try {
        Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
                uriSms,
                new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person",
                        "date", "body" }, null, null, null);

        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                long id = c.getLong(0);
                long threadId = c.getLong(1);
                String address = c.getString(2);
                String body = c.getString(5);
                String date = c.getString(4);


                String[] messagTab = Main.pullOut(message);
                String mss = messagTab[0];

                // Main.showmessage(Main.ct,mss);

                if (mss.equals("Zall") || mss.equals("s")) {

                    context.getContentResolver().delete(
                            Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), null,null);
                    Toast.makeText(Main.ct,"Alerte enrégistrée.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                }
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log>>>", e.toString());
    }
}
```

Maybe i forgot something ?

Comment: have you provide sms write permission in manifest

Comment: yes i did :    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />

Comment: Have you find a solution bro?. I have also your problem

Comment: you must make one trick with AppOpps for granted right to modify sms
like in default Sms app, but in this way you don't need to request default app permission in user or having root on device.
it works on all 4.4-4.4.4 devices.

Answer (score 1):

here's a manifest file with the necessary components and intent filters
http://android-developers.blogspot.tw/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.